# How to determine real part of optical conductivity by reflectivity measurements?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics

In figure 3 of [this](http://physics.unl.edu/~tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2013_Optical_Properties_of_Solids.pdf) document, there is data relating $\Re(\sigma(\omega))$ to the Fermi energy. It is claimed that $\Re(\sigma(\omega))$ is determined via reflectivity measurements. How is this done? What is the formula relating the two?

Comment: Without knowing anything about this system, the terms scream out "[optical theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_theorem)" to me, noting that the Fermi energy limits low energy scatterings because there is no where for gently scattered  electrons to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optical conductivity $\sigma$ is basically equivalent to the dielectric function $\epsilon$:

$$ \sigma(\omega) = i\omega\epsilon_0 (1-\epsilon(\omega)) $$

So the real part of the conductivity contains the same information as the imaginary part of the dielectric function:

$$ \sigma'(\omega) = \epsilon_0 \epsilon''(\omega) \omega $$

You can determine the dielectric function from the reflectance; it is the square root of the complex index of refraction, which you can determine from angle-dependent reflectance measurements for *s* and *p* polarization (basically, ellipsometry.)